Flutter Provider: ProviderNotFoundExcepttion. This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider of your choice
i have problem with Provider in flutter.
There is a main page when I create my Provider:
void main() async {
  await Supabase.initialize(
      url: <urlKey>,
      anonKey: <anonKey>);

  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Provider(
            create: (_) => DownloaderModel(),
            child: const GoogleSingUp()));
  }
}

Then I have GoogleSignUpPage:
final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

class GoogleSingUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoogleSingUp({ super.key });

  @override
  _GoogleSingUpState createState() => _GoogleSingUpState();
}

class _GoogleSingUpState extends State<GoogleSingUp> {
  String? _userId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        _userId = data.session?.user.id;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Column(
        children: [Text(_userId ?? 'Not signed in'), SignInButton(Buttons.Google, text: "Dupa", onPressed: () async {
          await _googleSignIn();
          if(context.mounted) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement<void, void>(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DwarvesDownloader()));
          }
          
        })],
      ))
    );
  }

  Future<void> _googleSignIn() async {

  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    clientId: iosClientId,
    serverClientId: webClientId,
  );
  final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
  final accessToken = googleAuth.accessToken;
  final idToken = googleAuth.idToken;

  if (accessToken == null) {
    throw 'No Access Token found.';
  }
  if (idToken == null) {
    throw 'No ID Token found.';
  }

  await supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken(
    provider: OAuthProvider.google,
    idToken: idToken,
    accessToken: accessToken,
  );
}
}

And I', trying to acces DownloaderModel from Provider in DwarvesDownloader:
class DwarvesDownloader extends StatelessWidget {
  const DwarvesDownloader({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DownloaderModel downloaderModel =
        Provider.of<DownloaderModel>(context, listen: false);

    return Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: downloaderModel.fetchData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                return const DwarvesListPage();
              }
            }));
  }
}

Do someone has any idea why I have such a problem? Provider is created in main so every widget inside app should have access to it?

How is DownloaderModel declared? Is it like class DownloaderModel with ChangeNotifier?

Try wrapping GoogleSingUp with Consumer.

here
Provider(
                create: (_) => DownloaderModel(),
                child: const GoogleSingUp()));

Instead of Provider try ChangeNotifierProvider

Try wraping your child: GoogleSignUp with Builder widget inside Provider
